# Hibernate/JPA doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, jpa

This is my third question this far trying to fix this. I already tried a lot of things, yet this keeps failing and throwing the exact same error on and on. Let's see if someone can help me this time.

See, this is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">


    <persistence-unit name="PruebaswebPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/nuevaConexion</jta-data-source>    
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

         <!-- Hibernate properties -->
        <properties>
                  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        </properties>        
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

It connects to a WAMP MySQL server via the JNDI connection pool "jdbc/nuevaConexion".

Here I try to use it (just testing purposes, as my entity!):

```
public class samplePersistence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PruebaswebPU");
        EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager();
        entitymanager.getTransaction().begin();

        testEntity ent = new testEntity();
        ent.setId(5l);
        ent.setNombre("One name");

        entitymanager.persist(ent);
        entitymanager.getTransaction().commit();

        entitymanager.close();
        emfactory.close();
    }
}
```

I always get this error, which is strange because it tells me to change the provider, but... it's already changed. Check:

```
> may 09, 2016 10:36:49 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
> logDeprecation WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated
> javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
> [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use
> [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. may 09, 2016
> 10:36:49 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
> WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated
> javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
> [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use
> [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. may 09, 2016
> 10:36:49 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
> WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated
> javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
> [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use
> [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. Exception in
> thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate
> persistence units     at
> org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:99)
>   at
> org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistence.java:93)
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:86)
>   at
> org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistence.java:101)
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:67)
>   at
> org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
>   at
> javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>   at
> javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>   at testing.samplePersistence.main(samplePersistence.java:20) Caused
> by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
> Error parsing XML [line : -1, column : -1] : cvc-complex-type.2.4.b:
> El contenido del elemento 'persistence' no está completo. Se esperaba
> uno de '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":persistence-unit}'.
> 
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.validate(PersistenceXmlParser.java:377)
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:310)
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:114)
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.doResolve(PersistenceXmlParser.java:104)
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits(PersistenceXmlParser.java:86)
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:95)
>   ... 8 more
> C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
> Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your persistence.xml file cannot be validated. Either it contains an invalid character (check the encoding, the BOM...) or the schema cannot be resolved (you should remove the declaration xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd").

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Hibernate version. Use a version upper or equal to 4.3.5.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/JPA-67